# SQL job ignoring IF condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs, cursors

I have a job with a few steps(that run reports information) and i added a query i wrote to the last step.
Sometimes the job fails because of factors i can not control (application issues)
and my query basically automatically executes jobs (the commands are running with a cursor in a table i made)when the current time is **after 8:45 am**, so the BI team won't need to do it themselves.
I checked it a few times and it seems to work when i execute it on ssms, but for some reason when it runs as a job it ignores the time condition and just execute the jobs anyway.

The query:

```
DECLARE @CodeID INT
declare @codecommand nvarchar(100)
DECLARE crsr CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR 
        SELECT CodeID, CodeCommand
        FROM exec_jobs_on_error
        ORDER BY codeid asc;

    OPEN crsr
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsr
    INTO @CodeID, @CodeCommand

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

BEGIN TRY
if exists (select 'true' where  LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)) > '08:45AM') 
begin
EXEC sp_executesql  @codeCommand

INSERT INTO the_daily_BI_error_log
            VALUES(@CodeID, 'Completed', GETDATE())

            end

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        declare @CodeError nvarchar(100)
            SET @CodeError = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
            insert into the_daily_BI_error_log
            values(@codeid, @CodeError, GETDATE())
            END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM crsr
        INTO @CodeID, @CodeCommand
        end
    CLOSE crsr
    DEALLOCATE crsr
```

Am i missing something in the condition writing?thanks.

Comment: The condition LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)) > '08:45AM' would work before 01:00PM, because string '08:45AM' > string '01:00PM'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a string comparison, not a time comparison. Moreover, the string you return does not include the leading `0`.

You might use something like below:

```
IF CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) > '08:45:00'
```

Here's further proof your expression returns a string:

```
sp_describe_first_result_set  N'SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))'
```

For me this shows an output of varchar(7).

Comment: okay thanks it seems to work on my testing job